# Thymeleaf Images binding that are located in server

Tags: java, email, thymeleaf

I need to read the image located in the server location in my html using thymeleaf, to send the image in mail not as an attachment but the content. I directly used something like this in my html,

```
<img alt="imagelogo" th:src = "${imageSrc}/logo.png" width="210" style="display: block;" />
```

My java code is like below,

```
String imgsrc = ""; // Some Path that has been set from my server property file.
final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
ctx.setVariable("imageSrc", imgsrc);
```

But I ran into the below exception,

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${imageSrc}/logo.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a problem with your expression.  Here are two examples that should work for you.  Using [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions):

```
th:src="|${imageSrc}/logo.png|"
```

or using [standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#using-expressions-in-urls):

```
th:src="@{{source}/logo.png(source=${imageSrc})}"
```